# Using meta refresh when making a web page

Tags: html

When making homepage, we use `<meta>` tag.

I have a question; I uploaded an image, *PictureA* to my website and linked it to *SiteABC* by using an image map.  Then when I click a specific part of *PictureA*,
the browser will load the site I linked.

I would like it to behave in this way:

After 10 seconds, I want *SiteABC* to redirect to *SiteDEF*. I know that I should use `<meta>` tag. However, when I used a `<meta>` tag in my html, the page which includes *PictureA* redirected to *SiteDEF*, instead of *SiteABC* redirecting to *SiteDEF*.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I did my best to try and improve the English in your question, but there's a good chance I didn't understand it correctly.  It's much more coherent now, however.

Comment: Can you specify if SiteABC/SiteDEF is loaded in the same window, or in another window? Or maybe in a frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a 302 (HTTP Redirect) issued from ABC site.  Since the direct mapping is not what you want to do.  Or it seems I am missing the real question.  If you want the server to replace the html dynamically I think you are opening up the potential for many issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the meta refresh tag on ABC site, not on the starting site.  This will allow you to have the user follow this path:

- User Visits home page
- User CLicks image map
- ABC loads
- 10 seconds elapses
- DEF loads

A 302 HTTP redirect on ABC will not allow it to load first, and then wait 10 seconds before loading DEF.